# About to setup KMS server for Volume activation

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, kms, licensing

I have searched and searched for any hints of how i should setup our KMS server for our coming installations of 2008(r2) servers and win7 clients. No luck, so here I am.

We've got around 20 developers switching to windows 7(about 50-80 more boxes when all apps are completely tested), and were using MAK keys at the moment, we got about 50-60 virtual servers(2003) for our test/demo environment that we could switch to 2008r2 without much fuss(data center licenses ftw).

My wish is for 1 server to handle all the KMS licenses, is it possible?
We got bunches of 1srver 2008 KMS licenses, 4 Data center licenses, and 1 kms key with 150 client licenses for win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My wish is for 1 server to handle all the KMS licenses, is it possible?

Yes, but remember to backup/plan for replacing it.

KMS is a separate download (e.g. here for [Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bbf2eb61-2b30-4f2d-bccd-df53e220b8e9&DisplayLang=en)). The download pages contain [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/) links (and [technet search](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-GB?query=kms&ac=8) gives a lot of links as well).

Comment: your technet search got me on the right track:) thx man!

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out i was on the wrong track, and tought there would be som verification of the keys internally so we cannot overuse our license. Then i found this in the Volume_Activation _2.0_MAK_KMS_KEY.doc from Microsoft:

> Each
>   KMS key provides for the activation of
>   six KMS host machines for up to 10
>   uses per host machine. Each host can
>   activate an unlimited number of
>   machines running Windows Server 2008,
>   Windows Vista Business, and/or Windows
>   Vista Enterprise editions.

And the Planning Guide explained that i only need the KMS license with the highest Access

Clients < Server Group A < Server Group B < Server group C(our Datacenter license)

So i'll just go with the Data center license.

Documents are found at the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9893F83E-C8A5-4475-B025-66C6B38B46E3&displaylang=en